# Recursive permutation function always returns empty list

Tags: haskell, recursion, permutation

I'm learning Haskell, and one of my practice functions was a simple recursive `permute`. I adapted [the solution described here](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2006-July/018298.html) and originally got this:

```
selections [] = []
selections (x:xs) = (x, xs) : [ (y, x:ys) | (y,ys) <- selections xs ]

permute xs = [y:ps | (y,ys) <- selections xs, ps <- permute ys]
```

(Yes, this could be shorter, but I was going for explicitness and clarity.)

However, this version of `permute` always returned an empty list! After flailing a bit, I got it to work by changing `permute` to:

```
permute [] = [[]]
permute xs = [y:ps | (y,ys) <- selections xs, ps <- permute ys]
```

However, I'm still perplexed as to **why the original version always returns an empty list**.

Comment: At least it should be clear from your program that the original version of `permute` cannot return any list containing `[]` as an element, because the element is always of the form `y:ps`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, the two are obviously very similar, so why not look in detail at where they disagree? The recursive portion is exactly the same in both, so first we can say that both versions do the *same thing* on non-empty lists. This sounds wrong because they give different results, but it's actually true in that they *perform the same operation on the result of the recursive call*.

The base case from the correct version is `permute [] = [[]]`, which is self-explanatory. The base case from the first version, however, is implicit in the list comprehension. Given the definition:

```
permute xs = [y:ps | (y,ys) <- selections xs, ps <- permute ys]
```

...we can substitute in `[]` for `xs` to see what happens:

```
permute [] = [y:ps | (y,ys) <- selections [], ps <- permute ys]
```

Given the definition `selections [] = []`, we can simplify to:

```
permute [] = [y:ps | (y,ys) <- [], ps <- permute ys]
```

...from which it is clear that no results are generated, so the whole list comprehension is empty, simplifying down to just:

```
permute [] = []
```

Now, consider the last recursive step before the base, substituting `[x]` as the argument:

```
permute [x] = [y:ps | (y,ys) <- selections [x], ps <- permute ys]
```

The definition of `selections` is `selections (x:xs) = (x, xs) : [ (y, x:ys) | (y,ys) <- selections xs ]`, substituting in `[x]` gives `selections [x] = (x, []) : [ (y, x:ys) | (y,ys) <- selections [] ]`. `selections []` evaluates to `[]`, so the entire list comprehension reduces to `[]` as well, giving `selections [x] = (x, []) : []` or just `selections [x] = [(x, [])]`.

Substitute that into `permute` as above:

```
permute [x] = [y:ps | (y,ys) <- [(x, [])], ps <- permute ys]
```

There's only one element in the list, so we can ignore the `<-` comprehension binding and substitute directly:

```
permute [x] = [y:ps | (y,ys) = (x, []), ps <- permute ys]

permute [x] = [ x:ps | ps <- permute []]
```

Having established that `permute []` evaluates to `[]`, we can substitute that in as well and find that the list comprehension again reduces to `[]`:

```
permute [x] = []
```

...which easily generalizes to returning `[]` for any input. The *working* version, however, uses the following definition:

```
permute [] = [[]]
```

In the final reduction of the final recursive step, this changes the substitutions to the following:

```
permute [x] = [ x:ps | ps <- permute []]

permute [x] = [ x:ps | ps <- [[]] ]
```

Since `ps` is being bound to something with a single element, we again can substitute directly:

```
permute [x] = (x:[])
```

Which is just saying that `permute [x] = [x]`.